# String reverse function is not working for odd length strings

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, debugging

I tried to write the following code in C++ to reverse a string. For some reason, when the string is of odd-length it gives a wrong output.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void swapWithOutThirdVar(char &a, char &b) {
    a = a + b;
    b = a - b;
    a = a - b;
}

void reverse(char string[]) {
    int length = 0;
    while (string[length] != '\0') {
        length++;
    }
    int left = 0, right = length - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
        swapWithOutThirdVar(string[left], string[right]);
        left++;
        right--;
    }
}

int main() {
    char string[25];
    cin>>string;

    reverse(string);
    cout<<string<<endl;
}
```

For example if I enter `lappy` to the console, the subsequent output is `yp`. I am new to programming, so please be kind to me no matter how stupid the underlying mistake is.

Comment: Consider what happens when you swap a variable with itself using your swap function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to resolve the error in your code, but the backbone error in your code lies in the swap function that you have defined *on your own.*

```
void swapWithOutThirdVar(char &a, char &b) {
    a = a + b;
    b = a - b;
    a = a - b;
}
```

I know that this is a very well-known function used to swap two variables without using a third variable. But it has two issues:

1. For certain values of `a` and `b`, the operation `a + b` can result in an overflow.
2. *(This is the case here)* If you run into passing the exact same variables to the function, the swap would end up being erratic. Here's why:

Let's say that you're passing the variable `char c` to both the arguments of the function. Since in your function the parameters are being passed by reference, the dummy variables `a` and `b` are actually *the same variables*, that is, they're aliases to the same `c`. In a nutshell, **`a` and `b` denote the same variable `c`**.
So, now when you do `a = a + b`, the operation actually results in `c = c + c`, which means that `c`'s *(ASCII)* value has been doubled by the end of execution of this statement.
The fun hits when the second statement comes into play. `b = a - b` results in `c = c - c`, which **assigns `0` to `c`**. *That's where you went wrong, kiddo.*
The third statement doesn't do anything good to the process. `a = a - b` results in `c = c - c`, which still makes `c` hold `0`.

So, your variable gets assigned the value `0`, instead of getting swapped with (itself?).

Now, you might be wondering where are you exactly ending up swapping the same variable, right?
When you're having an odd-length string, note that in the last iteration of the second `while` loop, the values of `left` and `right` are the same. In that case, `left` and `right` have the same indices for `string` and hence `string[left]` and `string[right]` are the same variables. The same variables are being passed to the swap function in that iteration.
Now, as I had stated earlier: passing the same variables to the swap function will end up handing a `0` to the variable that has been passed to it. For your example case, this is what `string` looks like at the end of the last iteration:
`['y', 'p' '\0', 'a', 'l']`

In C/C++, a `null` (`0`) marks the end of a string. Therefore, the *weird* output (`yp`) is justified.

In even-length strings, `left` will never be equal to `right` in any of the iterations of the second `while` loop. That's why, a same variable is never passed to the swap function, and that's why the `reverse` function works just as fine as the same variable is never passed to it.

Therefore, firstly you need to take care of the *same-variable* case. In case `a` and `b` are the same variable, you simply return from the function as swapping a variable with itself is techically pointless. Utilise the fact that if two variables are basically references to the same variable, they must be having the same address.

```
void swapWithOutThirdVar(char &a, char &b) {
    if (&a == &b)
        return;

    a = a + b;
    b = a - b;
    a = a - b;
}
```

But this doesn't resolve the overflow issue. So, you need to do something else.

Assuming that this is a programming assignment problem in which you need to implement *everything on your own*, you can go for the XOR-swap which uses bitwise XOR to swap two variables. Going by the name of your swap function, I think you're aware of the vintage three-variable swapping technique and that using a third variable for swapping is also a *restriction* in your assignment.

Operating XOR on two numbers doesn't result in overflow, so that problem is fixed. The XOR method although, doesn't independently resolve the same-variable case and ends up handing the variable a `0` in the first statement itself, so you need to retain the address equality checking part:

```
void swapWithOutThirdVar(char &a, char &b) {
    if (&a == &b)
        return;

    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;
}
```

Also, you can leave the swap function as it is and slightly modify the second `while` loop's condition to resolve the error:
For an odd-length string, the middle character's position is left unchanged when reversed. Come to think of it: the `left`-equals-`right` case arises when `left` and `right` (both) are pointing to the middle character of the string. So, the loop needs to run only as long as `left < right` holds `true`. For an even-length string, `left` never becomes equal to `right`. The `while` loop ends right when `left` and `right` are indices of the two adjacent middle elements of the string. Therefore, the `left < right` modification doesn't hurt the even-length case. So, the corresponding fix would be:

```
void reverse(char string[]) {
    int length = 0;
    while (string[length] != '\0') {
        length++;
    }
    int left = 0, right = length - 1;
    while (left < right) {
        swapWithOutThirdVar(string[left], string[right]);
        left++;
        right--;
    }
}
```

This concludes the bug explanation and rectification part. But in case this isn't for a programming assignment in which you have to implement everything on your own, that is, you don't have *restrictions*, you should consider the following instead:

Judging by the `using namespace std;` in your code, it appears that it was meant for C++0x or beyond. So, you should be considering the following things:

1. From C++0x onwards, you already have a predefined swap function (`std :: swap`). You can use that instead. Overflows and same-variables being passed to it aren't an issue here. See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).
2. You're using a C-style string in your program. C-style strings are not recommended anymore. Moreover, you're using C++0x or beyond. So, you should be using `std :: string` instead. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/).
3. You can use the `reverse` function from the `algorithm` header. See [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/).

Comment: *"for certain values of a and b, the operation a + b can result in an overflow."* This is true but irrelevant; the effect of the overflow will be undone by overflows on the other lines. The swap algorithm is correct even when overflows occur, because `+` and `-` are still inverse operations in modular arithmetic.

Comment: @kaya3 Most of the time. The official behaviour of signed integer overflow is undefined.

Comment: @kaya3 — modular arithmetic only applies to **unsigned** types. `char` is not required to be unsigned, and it often is signed. Arithmetic overflow is signed types means that the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: That's indeed a beautiful and very detailed explanation. Yes, it was for a programming assignment in which we are not allowed to use library functions but I think my teacher will allow us to at least use the predefined swap function. I'll definitely check out the C++ 0x functions.

Comment: @PeteBecker You're right about undefined behaviour, that is a good point. That said, in practice `+` will be compiled to the same machine instruction regardless of whether the integer is signed or unsigned, as will `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Your swap implementation is incorrect if a and b point to the same memory location.

So you shall fix your loop:

```
while (left < right) {
    swapWithOutThirdVar(string[left], string[right]);
    left++;
    right--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a peculiarity of C++'s call-by-reference semantics. Your swap function will give unexpected (and incorrect) results when both `&a` and `&b` are the same memory address. This occurs when `left == right`.

Consider the following substitution, where I've changed `a` and `b` to both be the same variable, `middleLetter`:

```cpp
    middleLetter = middleLetter + middleLetter;
    middleLetter = middleLetter - middleLetter;
    middleLetter = middleLetter - middleLetter;
```

The second line sets `middleLetter` to zero, and the third line leaves it as zero.

The simple fix is to change your loop condition to `while(left < right)`. There is no need to swap the middle letter with itself anyway.

Comment: It is **not** a “peculiarity of C++’s call-by-reference semantics”. It is a logical error in the algorithm. You’d get the same result if the function took pointers to its arguments, or if you tried to swap a variable with itself by writing that code directly in line.

Comment: It is a peculiarity of call-by-reference that two variables with different names can be bound to the same memory location. If they were pointers then the code wouldn't be `a = a + b;`, it would be `*a = *a + *b`. In call-by-value semantics it is not possible for an assignment to one parameter to change the value of a different parameter.

Comment: Yes, obviously, with pointers you have to dereference the pointers. That doesn’t change the fact that this code clobbers the original value when you try to swap a value with itself. The problem isn’t in the language feature used. It’s with the **logic** of the function itself. The function is fragile, and the risk greatly outweighs the minor “benefit” of avoiding a local variable.

Comment: I didn't say there is a **problem** with the language feature. I said it is peculiar. If you think it is not peculiar for an assignment `a = ...` to change the value of a different variable `b`, then you are just going to have to accept that other people do tend to find that peculiar, in a way which `*a = ` is not. By the way, I did not describe the logic of that function as correct, I said it gives incorrect results. That said, if the function's purpose is to swap the contents of **two** memory locations, then the logical error is in the code which calls it with just one memory location.